# what is meaning of public function catalogCategoryCollectionLoadAfter ($observer) in Observer.php

Tags: magento

Can any one please tell me the meaning of `catalogCategoryCollectionLoadAfter()` in **Observer.php**

```
public function catalogCategoryCollectionLoadAfter ($observer)
```

Comment: Any particular Observer.php or is the question to guess what the question is?

Comment: which Observer.php (full path please)?

Comment: This method is not a standard Magento method. It can be any custom observer method like Vinai's `ZetaPrints_AccessControl_Model_Observer`, or Josh's `Prattski_HideEmptyCategories_Model_Observer`, or whatever. Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for you. It is to hide empty categories.

You can google too - right click on catalogCategoryCollectionLoadAfter, google it, and, top of the list, you'll see what is going on here.